# Cannot run tensorflow examples

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to run this tensorflow example: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/skflow/text_classification_character_cnn.py

However it keeps failing at the stage to open the tar file. This is the error message I am getting:

```
Successfully downloaded dbpedia_csv.tar.gz 1613 bytes.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "text_classification_character_cnn.py", line 110, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/Users/alechewitt/Envs/solar_detection/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 30, in run
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "text_classification_character_cnn.py", line 87, in main
    'dbpedia', test_with_fake_data=FLAGS.test_with_fake_data, size='large')
  File "/Users/alechewitt/Envs/solar_detection/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/__init__.py", line 64, in load_dataset
    return DATASETS[name](size, test_with_fake_data)
  File "/Users/alechewitt/Envs/solar_detection/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/text_datasets.py", line 48, in load_dbpedia
    maybe_download_dbpedia(data_dir)
  File "/Users/alechewitt/Envs/solar_detection/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/text_datasets.py", line 40, in maybe_download_dbpedia
    tfile = tarfile.open(archive_path, 'r:*')
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 1672, in open
    raise ReadError("file could not be opened successfully")
tarfile.ReadError: file could not be opened successfully
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Open the tar file using the full path. BTW the link you gave is 404 not found.

Answer (score 0):

When you get that error, you can look at the downloaded dbpedia_dsv.tar.gz in a text editor, and you might find that it is actually a 404 webpage. The file you want seems to be available here as well (I found this link [here](https://github.com/zhangxiangxiao/Crepe)):
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0Bz8a_Dbh9Qhbfll6bVpmNUtUcFdjYmF2SEpmZUZUcVNiMUw1TWN6RDV3a0JHT3kxLVhVR2M
Download that file (at your own risk) and replace it manually. Then you can run your script again.

Comment: From source code the link is 

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0Bz8a_Dbh9Qhbfll6bVpmNUtUcFdjYmF2SEpmZUZUcVNiMUw1TWN6RDV3a0JHT3kxLVhVR2M

and I get 404 error with it.


I download dataset from your link, it works.